# This is not a function; it cannot be applied ackermann function

Tags: ocaml

Hello I'm trying to do a ackermann function and I'm stuck because it gives me this :

```
Error: This expression has type int
  This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

here is my function :

```
let rec acker m n = 
  if (m = 0) then n + 1 
  else if (n = 0) then acker ((m - 1) 1) 
  else acker ((m - 1) acker (m (n - 1)));;
```

Comment: The OCaml syntax for calling a function `f` with two arguments `x` and `y` is `f x y`.

Comment: Nope, you wrote `f (x y)`.

Answer (score 3):

```ml
acker ((m-1) 1)
```

reads as apply the function `acker` to the result of

```
(m-1) 1
```

and `m-1` is an integer, not a function.
You want

```ml
acker (m-1) 1
```